# How to move svg image with dragging another element?

Tags: jquery, svg, snap.svg

I'm wondering if that possible to move an image which under another element with dragging. I don't know how to describe it clearly, please take a look on the demo bellow.

https://jsfiddle.net/david7418/o497akje/10/

I want to trigger drag event form the top of transparent photo and move the another photo under it but not itself.

```
 $(function() {
       obj = Snap(".cat");
       //Enable drag event
       obj.drag();
 }
```

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You can use pointer-events:none in css to ignore the drag from the top layer. It's not really clear if that's what you want though. An example.. https://jsfiddle.net/o497akje/12/

Comment: Thank you. It's amazing, I don't know how it works. There is a little problem. If I add pointer-events:none on the image, it seems to break all the events on elements inside the svg. https://jsfiddle.net/david7418/o497akje/14/. I added click event on 3 g elements, it can't be triggered if pointer-events:none exist.

Comment: Yes, if you disable pointer-events. It will disable clicks as well. So it depends really what you are after. Only other thing I can think of is putting the drag and clicks on the svg paper and detecting  from the event.target what to do.

Comment: Yeah, I think I could remove the pointer-events:none style, then everything works find. But that might cause some user experience problems. I won't know when to remove the style unless user click "Done" button. Is there any example for the event.target? What can I do after the event target has been detected?

Comment: @lan Could you please make a new answer for pointer-events:none one? I think this is a correct answer. I will mark it as the correct answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use

```
pointer-events:none
```

with css to make an svg element not create a mouse event.